# Hide Column in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to hide a column in SharePoint 2007 list based on Users.

When user submit a request the status column should be hidden and the value set as pending.

When Admin logged in he/she should able to edit the status.

Is there any way I can achieve this with out writing CUSTOM CODE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Deepu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No custom code makes it tough.  What about creating two views.  one view has the column and another does not.  Then create two sharepoint web pages and add the first view with the column to one, and the second view without the column to the other.  Then put a security group or audience on the pages, so the appropriate one shows up for the user.  Not great, but could be an option.

Comment: That is the only option even I thought.. lets try the same and keep you posted.. Thanks Shane..

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to do something with a custom field type - this guy has a solution very close to what you need - however there is custom code involved.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/Dressel-Gogolowicz-wss-security

The only other thing i could think of is to deploy a custom fldtypes.xsl to the hive and pattern match against your column. Then perhaps you could do some for of xsl transformation to show/hide the column - not sure how you'd indicate if a user is an admin or not though.

You are really limiting yourself by ruling out custom code.

Best of luck,
Shane

Comment: Unfortunately I am not suppose to write any custom code. Using custom content type it is possible to hide and I can use workflow to set the status value but how when admin logged in he/she should able to see and edit the status.. .

any idea ?

Comment: Without using custom code like the example above I really don't know any solution. Is there any reason you're not allowed write custom code, as that is really limiting your options.

Comment: Yes the reason is the client want's only customization/configuration using site and designer 2007 no custom coding required...

Comment: Thats a pity, if you do find a solution please let me know as I'd be very interested in how you manage it.

Best of Luck,
Shane

Comment: Sure will do it

Thanks
Deepu